# Under Spring Boot, Hibernate says a row in table does not exist when it does

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am running a simple query using JPA -> Hibernate -> JDBC -> Oracle.

The query basically is:

```
select * from mstrgenstate where stateshort='TX';
```

When I run it at the Oracle Level, I get:

```
   STATEID  COUNTRYID STA STATEMED        STATELONG
---------- ---------- --- --------------- ------------------------------
         1          1 TX  Texas           Texas
```

When I run it in Java using JPA and Hibernate,  I get that no record exists in the table. The messages I am getting (with the trace set on) are listed below. The entity code (**Mstrgenstate.java**) was generated using **Hibernate**. The data-access code (**MstrgenstateDAO.java**) is using the **CrudRepository**

Is there some kind of special thing one has to do in order to get data out of the DB?

TIA

**Update**
**I added to the DAO file:**

```
public List<Mstrgenstate> findByStateid ( BigDecimal stateid );
```

**And to the controller:**

```
List<Mstrgenstate> testme = statedao.findByStateid(new BigDecimal(1));
System.out.println("first test here " + testme.size());
```

**I got the following result- it worked**

```
2017-07-21 15:46:13.344 DEBUG 10496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select mstrgensta0_.stateid as stateid1_6_, mstrgensta0_.countryid as countryid2_6_, mstrgensta0_.statelong as statelong3_6_, mstrgensta0_.statemed as statemed4_6_, mstrgensta0_.stateshort as stateshort5_6_ from oraapps.mstrgenstate mstrgensta0_ where mstrgensta0_.stateid=?
2017-07-21 15:46:13.477 TRACE 10496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [NUMERIC] - [1]
2017-07-21 15:46:13.487 TRACE 10496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([stateid1_6_] : [NUMERIC]) - [1]
2017-07-21 15:46:13.496 TRACE 10496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([countryid2_6_] : [NUMERIC]) - [1]
2017-07-21 15:46:13.497 TRACE 10496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([statelong3_6_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Texas]
2017-07-21 15:46:13.498 TRACE 10496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([statemed4_6_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Texas]
2017-07-21 15:46:13.498 TRACE 10496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([stateshort5_6_] : [VARCHAR]) - [TX ]
first test here 1
```

> So what I am seeing is that retrieving the data works fine for
>   integers but when one uses characters, there appears to be some kind
>   of problem. The DB is Oracle - is there a bug somewhere in all of
>   this? Below is what I got when I tried to fetch using a string (TX)

**messages I am gettting**

```
017-07-21 14:36:42.198  INFO 20212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-07-21 14:36:42.438 DEBUG 20212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select mstrgensta0_.stateid as stateid1_6_, mstrgensta0_.countryid as countryid2_6_, mstrgensta0_.statelong as statelong3_6_, mstrgensta0_.statemed as statemed4_6_, mstrgensta0_.stateshort as stateshort5_6_ from oraapps.mstrgenstate mstrgensta0_ where mstrgensta0_.stateshort=?
2017-07-21 14:36:42.531 TRACE 20212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [TX]
2017-07-21 14:36:42.557 DEBUG 20212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select mstrgensta0_.stateid as stateid1_6_, mstrgensta0_.countryid as countryid2_6_, mstrgensta0_.statelong as statelong3_6_, mstrgensta0_.statemed as statemed4_6_, mstrgensta0_.stateshort as stateshort5_6_ from oraapps.mstrgenstate mstrgensta0_ where mstrgensta0_.statelong=?
2017-07-21 14:36:42.557 TRACE 20212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [TX]

Fri Jul 21 14:36:42 CDT 2017 => DATA_INPUT_ERROR :   => CLASS :  CustomerController => EMSG-20008 - finding state id for state name : ->TX<- has failed  State passed in TX number of items found 0
ccinfw.messages.DataInputError: Fri Jul 21 14:36:42 CDT 2017 => DATA_INPUT_ERROR :   => CLASS :  CustomerController => EMSG-20008 - finding state id for state name : ->TX<- has failed  State passed in TX number of items found 0
    at ccinfw.controller.CustomerController.addCustomer(CustomerController.java:107)
```

**code for controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Lawncustomer> addCustomer(
            @RequestBody CustomerIOPOJO input) throws Exception {

        try {

            Lawncustomer cust = new Lawncustomer();

            cust.setTenantid(input.getTenantid());
            cust.setCustomerid(new BigDecimal(200));
            cust.setFirstname(input.getFirstname());
            cust.setLastname(input.getLastname());
            cust.setCellphoneno(input.getCellphoneno());
            cust.setEmail(input.getEmail());
            cust.setAddress(input.getAddress());
            cust.setCity(input.getCity());

            if (input.getState() == null
                    || input.getState().trim().length() <= 1) {
                throw new DataInputError
                        ( " => CLASS :  " +   this.getClass().getSimpleName() 
                        + " => EMSG-20000 - invalid state sent in for evaluation - make sure 2-char def is used. Passed in : "
                        + input.getState() + " EMail processed " + input.getEmail() );
            }


            List<Mstrgenstate> statefound;
            statefound = statedao.findByStateshort(input.getState());

            if (statefound.size() > 1 || statefound.size() < 0 ){                           
                throw new ApplicationError
                ( " => CLASS :  " +   this.getClass().getSimpleName() 
                + " => EMSG-20012 - invalid number of items found for STATE: ->" + input.getState() + "<- verify DB entries " 
                + " State passed in " + input.getState());
            }

            if (statefound.size() == 0 ) {
                statefound = statedao.findByStatelong(input.getState());

                if (statefound.size() != 1) {                           
                    throw new DataInputError
                    ( " => CLASS :  " +   this.getClass().getSimpleName() 
                    + " => EMSG-20008 - finding state id for state name : ->" + input.getState() + "<- has failed " 
                    + " State passed in " + input.getState() + " number of items found " + statefound.size() );  
                }
            }

            cust.setStateid(statefound.get(0).getStateid());
            cust.setZipcode(input.getZipcode());

            MapFunctionality mapping = new MapFunctionality(input.getAddress(),
                    input.getCity(), input.getState(), input.getZipcode());
            mapping.calcLatLongPositions();
            cust.setLoclatitude(mapping.getCalclat());
            cust.setLoclongitude(mapping.getCalclon());

            customer.save(cust);

            return new ResponseEntity<Lawncustomer>(cust, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeError
            ( " => CLASS :  " +   this.getClass().getSimpleName() 
            + " => EMSG-20010 - finding state id for state name : ->" + input.getState() + "<- has failed "
            + " EMail processed " + input.getEmail());
        }
    }
```

**MstrgenstateDAO.java (using CrudRepository)**

```
package ccinfw.general.dao;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ccinfw.general.entities.Mstrgenstate;


@Transactional
@Repository
public interface MstrgenstateDAO extends CrudRepository<Mstrgenstate, BigDecimal>{

    public List<Mstrgenstate> findByStateshort( String stateshort );

    public List<Mstrgenstate> findByStatelong( String statelong );

}
```

**Mstrgenstate.java (generated by Hibernate)**

```
// Generated Jul 16, 2017 9:14:14 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Mstrgenstate generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "MSTRGENSTATE", schema = "ORAAPPS")
public class Mstrgenstate implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * serial item added as required
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3354389768807065484L;

    private BigDecimal stateid;
    private BigDecimal countryid;
    private String stateshort;
    private String statemed;
    private String statelong;

    public Mstrgenstate() {
    }

    public Mstrgenstate(BigDecimal stateid) {
        this.stateid = stateid;
    }

    public Mstrgenstate(BigDecimal stateid, BigDecimal countryid,
            String stateshort, String statemed, String statelong) {
        this.stateid = stateid;
        this.countryid = countryid;
        this.stateshort = stateshort;
        this.statemed = statemed;
        this.statelong = statelong;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STATEID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getStateid() {
        return this.stateid;
    }

    public void setStateid(BigDecimal stateid) {
        this.stateid = stateid;
    }

    @Column(name = "COUNTRYID", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public BigDecimal getCountryid() {
        return this.countryid;
    }

    public void setCountryid(BigDecimal countryid) {
        this.countryid = countryid;
    }

    @Column(name = "STATESHORT", length = 3)
    public String getStateshort() {
        return this.stateshort;
    }

    public void setStateshort(String stateshort) {
        this.stateshort = stateshort;
    }

    @Column(name = "STATEMED", length = 15)
    public String getStatemed() {
        return this.statemed;
    }

    public void setStatemed(String statemed) {
        this.statemed = statemed;
    }

    @Column(name = "STATELONG", length = 30)
    public String getStatelong() {
        return this.statelong;
    }

    public void setStatelong(String statelong) {
        this.statelong = statelong;
    }

}
```

Comment: where exactly do you use jpa to get your data?

Comment: I make the call using: "statefound = statedao.findByStateshort(input.getState());" in the controller code.

Comment: and where you are saving your data?

Comment: Into a table on the DB side. It is an Oracle table. But, the problem is that I need to get the STATEID  ~before~ I save he data to the Oracle table. There is one table with all of the states. The problem is that when I do a select (or attempt to get) data from the table holding all of the states, Hibernate says there is nothing there -

Comment: select * from mstrgenstate where stateshort='TX';
works from the DB command line interface

Comment: But when using this Hibernate stuff, it does not. I do not see why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just changed the column to VARCHAR and everything worked fine in the DB. I guess the hibernate generation program registered my CHAR(3) to VARCHAR. Silly mistake - mods, you can remove post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a DESC of your table ?

I Suspect your STATESHORT Column is a CHAR(3) AND not a VARCHAR. The Content of your column is not 'TX' but 'TX ' so the row is not seen.

Comment: Yes, this is what I found (see my last post). The table was defined as CHAR(3) and Hibernate was looking for VARCHAR. I changed it in the DB to VARCHAR and everything worked.